# How can I strengthen this function? I want it to give me an estimated date of hearing back from grad school applications

Tags: r

I created a function to give me an estimated date of hearing back from grad school applications using the median length of days between each theGradCafe submission and January 1st. I separated submissions into three categories -- general, Interview, Acceptance, Rejection.

This is my first R project and I would love to get some criticisms on how to clean things up with it; the code is really clunky but seems to do the job.

Here it is:

```
grad=function(x,y){
  #just one link?
  if(missing(y)) {
    #inserting the link
    pat="U.*$"
    require(rvest)
    require(stringr)
    require(dplyr)
    #converting link to text
    h=read_html(x)
    nodes=h %>%
      html_nodes(".tcol3")
    #cleaning up text
    gadmin=sapply(nodes, html_text)[2:length(nodes)]
    gadmin=sub('.*on', '', gadmin)
    a=sub('.*on', '', gadmin)
    gadmin=sub(pat, '', gadmin) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    #finishing
    gadmint_c=format(gadmin, "%m-%d") %>%
      as.Date("%m-%d")
    origin_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
    #date estimates
    lengthp=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_c, origin_date))
    lengthp=ifelse(lengthp >=334, lengthp-365, lengthp)
    lengthp=ifelse(lengthp > 5.5*sd(lengthp, na.rm=T) | lengthp < -5.5*sd(lengthp, na.rm=T), NA, lengthp)
    estd=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthp, na.rm=T)
    estd=format(estd, format="%m-%d")
    print(paste("You should hear SOMETHING  by", estd))
    invisible(estd)
    #interview estimates
    nodes_i=nodes[which(str_extract(as.character(nodes), "Interview") =="Interview")]
    gadmin_i=sapply(nodes_i, html_text)
    gadmin_i=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_i)
    gadmin_i= sub(pat, '', gadmin_i) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    #finishing interviews
    gadmint_ci=format(gadmin_i, "%m-%d") %>%
      as.Date("%m-%d")
    origin_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
    #interview estimates
    lengthpi=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_ci, origin_date))
    lengthpi=ifelse(lengthpi >=334, lengthpi-365, lengthpi)
    lengthpi=ifelse(lengthpi > 5.5*sd(lengthpi, na.rm=T) | lengthpi < -5.5*sd(lengthpi, na.rm=T), NA, lengthpi)
    estdi=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthpi, na.rm=T)
    estdi=format(estdi, format="%m-%d")
    print(paste("You should hear about Interviews by ", estdi))
    invisible(estdi)
    #acceptance/rejectance estimates
    nodes_r=nodes[c(which(str_extract(as.character(nodes), "Rejected") =="Rejected"))]
    nodes_a=nodes[c(which(str_extract(as.character(nodes), "Accepted") =="Accepted"))]
    gadmin_r=sapply(nodes_r, html_text)
    gadmin_a=sapply(nodes_a, html_text)
    gadmin_r=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_r)
    gadmin_a=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_a)
    gadmin_r= sub(pat, '', gadmin_r) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadmin_a= sub(pat, '', gadmin_a) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    #finishing acceptance/rejectance
    gadmint_car_r=format(gadmin_r, format="%m-%d") %>%
      as.Date("%m-%d")
   gadmint_car_a=format(gadmin_a, format="%m-%d") %>%
     as.Date("%m-%d")
    origin_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
    #acceptance/rejections estimates
    lengthpar_r=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_car_r, origin_date))
    lengthpar_a=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_car_a, origin_date))
    lengthpar_r=ifelse(lengthpar_r >=334, lengthpar_r-365, lengthpar_r)
    lengthpar_r=ifelse(lengthpar_r > 5.5*sd(lengthpar_r, na.rm=T) | lengthpar_r < -5.5*sd(lengthpar_r, na.rm=T), NA, lengthpar_r)
    lengthpar_a=ifelse(lengthpar_a >=334, lengthpar_a-365, lengthpar_a)
    lengthpar_a=ifelse(lengthpar_a > 5.5*sd(lengthpar_a, na.rm=T) | lengthpar_a < -5.5*sd(lengthpar_a, na.rm=T), NA, lengthpar_a)
    estdar_r=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthpar_r, na.rm=T)
    estdar_a=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthpar_a, na.rm=T)
    estdar_r=format(estdar_r, format="%m-%d")
    estdar_a=format(estdar_a, format="%m-%d")
    print(paste("You should hear about  Rejections by", estdar_r))
    print(paste("You should hear about  Acceptances by", estdar_a))
    invisible(estdar_r)
    invisible(estdar_a)
  } else {
    #just two links?
    #inserting the link
    pat="U.*$"
    require(rvest)
    require(dplyr)
    #converting link to text
    hx=read_html(x)
    hy=read_html(y)
    nodesx=hx %>%
      html_nodes(".tcol3")
    nodesy=hy %>%
      html_nodes(".tcol3")
    #cleaning up text
    gadminx=sapply(nodesx, html_text)[2:length(nodesx)]
    gadminy=sapply(nodesy, html_text)[2:length(nodesy)]
    gadminx=sub('.*on', '', gadminx)
    ax=sub('.*on', '', gadminx)
    gadminx=sub(pat, '', gadminx) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadminy=sub('.*on', '', gadminy)
    ay=sub('.*on', '', gadminy)
    gadminy=sub(pat, '', gadminy) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadmin=c(gadminx, gadminy)
    #finishing
    gadmint_c=format(gadmin, format="%m-%d")%>%
      as.Date("%m-%d")
    origin_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
    #date estimates
    lengthp=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_c, origin_date))
    lengthp=ifelse(lengthp >=334, lengthp-365, lengthp)
    lengthp=ifelse(lengthp > 5.5*sd(lengthp, na.rm=T) | lengthp < -5.5*sd(lengthp, na.rm=T), NA, lengthp)
    estd=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthp, na.rm=T)
    estd=format(estd, format="%m-%d")
    print(paste("You should hear SOMETHING  by", estd))
    invisible(estd)
    #interview estimates
    nodes_ix=nodesx[which(str_extract(as.character(nodesx), "Interview") =="Interview")]
    nodes_iy=nodesy[which(str_extract(as.character(nodesy), "Interview") =="Interview")]
    gadmin_ix=sapply(nodes_ix, html_text)
    gadmin_iy=sapply(nodes_iy, html_text)
    gadmin_ix=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_ix)
    gadmin_ix= sub(pat, '', gadmin_ix) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadmin_iy=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_iy)
    gadmin_iy= sub(pat, '', gadmin_iy) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    #finishing interviews
    gadmint_ci=c(gadmin_ix, gadmin_iy)
    gadmint_ci=format(gadmint_ci, "%m-%d")%>%
      as.Date("%m-%d")
    origin_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
    #interview estimates
    lengthpi=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_ci, origin_date))
    lengthpi=ifelse(lengthpi >=334, lengthpi-365, lengthpi)
    lengthpi=ifelse(lengthpi > 5.5*sd(lengthpi, na.rm=T) | lengthpi < -5.5*sd(lengthpi, na.rm=T), NA, lengthpi)
    estdi=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthpi, na.rm=T)
    estdi=format(estdi, format="%m-%d")
    print(paste("You should hear about Interviews by ", estdi))
    invisible(estdi)
    #acceptance/rejectance estimates
    nodes_rx=nodesx[c(which(str_extract(as.character(nodesx), "Rejected") =="Rejected"))]
    nodes_ax=nodesx[which(str_extract(as.character(nodesx), "Accepted") =="Accepted")]
    nodes_ry=nodesy[c(which(str_extract(as.character(nodesy), "Rejected") =="Rejected"))]
    nodes_ay=nodesy[which(str_extract(as.character(nodesy), "Accepted") =="Accepted")]
    gadmin_rx=sapply(nodes_rx, html_text)
    gadmin_ax=sapply(nodes_ax, html_text)
    gadmin_ry=sapply(nodes_ry, html_text)
    gadmin_ay=sapply(nodes_ay, html_text)
    gadmin_rx=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_rx)
    gadmin_ax=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_ax)
    gadmin_ry=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_ry)
    gadmin_ay=sub('.*on', '', gadmin_ay)
    gadmin_rx= sub(pat, '', gadmin_rx) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadmin_ax=sub(pat, '', gadmin_ax) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadmin_ry= sub(pat, '', gadmin_ry) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadmin_ay=sub(pat, '', gadmin_ay) %>%
      as.Date("%d %B %Y")
    gadmin_r=c(gadmin_rx, gadmin_ry)
    gadmin_a=c(gadmin_ax, gadmin_ay)
    #finishing acceptance/rejectance
    gadmint_c_r=format(gadmin_r, format="%m-%d")%>%
      as.Date("%m-%d")
    gadmint_c_a=format(gadmin_a, format="%m-%d") %>%
      as.Date("%m-%d")
    origin_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
    #acceptance/rejections estimates
    lengthpar_r=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_c_r, origin_date))
    lengthpar_a=as.numeric(julian(gadmint_c_a, origin_date))
    lengthpar_r=ifelse(lengthpar_r >=334, lengthpar_r-365, lengthpar_r)
    lengthpar_r=ifelse(lengthpar_r > 5.5*sd(lengthpar_r, na.rm=T) | lengthpar_r < -5.5*sd(lengthpar_r,na.rm=T), NA, lengthpar_r)
    lengthpar_a=ifelse(lengthpar_a >=334, lengthpar_a-365, lengthpar_a)
    lengthpar_a=ifelse(lengthpar_a > 5.5*sd(lengthpar_a, na.rm=T) | lengthpar_a < -5.5*sd(lengthpar_a, na.rm=T), NA, lengthpar_a)
    estd_a=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthpar_a, na.rm=T)
    estd_r=as.Date("2021-01-01")+median(lengthpar_r, na.rm=T)
    estd_r=format(estd_r, format="%m-%d")
    estd_a=format(estd_a, format="%m-%d")
    print(paste("You should hear about Acceptance by ", estd_a))
    print(paste("You should hear about Rejection by ", estd_r))
    invisible(estd_a)
    invisible(estd_r)
  }
}
```

So for example, if I wanted to look at Stanford submissions, I would type `grad("https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250")` and get back:

```
 grad("https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250")
[1] "You should hear SOMETHING  by 03-21"
[1] "You should hear about Interviews by  12-18"
[1] "You should hear about  Rejections by 02-12"
[1] "You should hear about  Acceptances by 03-20"
```

Or, if I applied to Stanford and Harvard:

```
 grad("https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250", "https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=harvard&t=a&o=&pp=250")
[1] "You should hear SOMETHING  by 03-17"
[1] "You should hear about Interviews by  12-18"
[1] "You should hear about Acceptance by  03-18"
[1] "You should hear about Rejection by  03-05"
```

The reason why SOMETHING is sometimes behind the others is because it's general, lumping everything in together, while the others are more specific.

Comment: This is quite a bit of code. Without reading every single line, can you advise what differs between the `if` and `else` block?

Comment: @Parfait Sorry about that! I was reading on Stack Overflow and that was their recommendation for specifying optional arguments in R functions.  The ```if``` specifies the first link which is required, while the ```else``` specifies the second link which is optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider breaking up your repetitive operations into separate functions. And specifically for `grad` function use R's [ellipsis feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057341/1422451), allowing you to pass many URLs with same call. Both steps will keep your code DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself). Finally, heed R's emphasis on *everything that exists is an object* and store your results in list of data frames (one for each URL) via `lapply` iteration instead of a one-time printout without persistent data.

#### Functions

- Space out your sections and operators
- Line break long calls
- Use `<-` operator for object assignment
- Remove multiple `invisible` for single `return`
- Avoid pipes `%>%` for simple one nest like `as.Date`

**`node_subset`**

```r
node_subset <- function(nodes, search_word=NA) {  
  if(is.na(search_word)) {
    sub_nodes <- nodes
  } else {
    sub_nodes <- nodes[which(str_extract(as.character(nodes), search_word)==search_word)]
  }
  
  pat <- "U.*$"
  gadmin <- sapply(sub_nodes, html_text)
  gadmin <- sub('.*on', '', gadmin)
  gadmin <-  as.Date(sub(pat, '', gadmin), format="%d %B %Y")
  gadmin_dt <- as.Date(format(gadmin, "%m-%d"), format="%m-%d")
  
  return(gadmin_dt)
}
```

**`date_calc`**

```r
date_calc <- function(param_dt, origin_date=as.Date("2021-01-01")) {  
  lengthp <- as.numeric(julian(param_dt, origin_date))
  lengthp <- ifelse(lengthp >= 334, lengthp-365, lengthp)
  lengthp <- ifelse(lengthp > 5.5 * sd(lengthp, na.rm=TRUE) |
                      lengthp < -5.5 * sd(lengthp, na.rm=TRUE), NA, lengthp)
  estd <- as.Date("2021-01-01") + median(lengthp, na.rm=TRUE)
  estd <- format(estd, format="%m-%d")
  
  return(estd)
}
```

**`grad`**

```r
grad <- function(...) {  
  lapply(list(...), function(x) {
  
    #inserting the link
    require(rvest)
    require(stringr)
    require(dplyr)
    
    #converting link to text
    h <- read_html(x)
    nodes <- html_nodes(h, ".tcol3")
    
    #cleaning up text
    gadmint_c <- node_subset(nodes)
    gadmint_ci <- node_subset(nodes, "Interview")
    gadmint_car_r <- node_subset(nodes, "Rejected")
    gadmint_car_a <- node_subset(nodes, "Accepted")
    
    #date estimates
    estd <- date_calc(gadmint_c)
    print(paste("You should hear SOMETHING  by", estd))
  
    #interview estimates
    estdi <- date_calc(gadmint_ci)
    print(paste("You should hear about Interviews by ", estdi))
    
    #acceptance/rejections estimates
    estdar_r <- date_calc(gadmint_car_r)
    print(paste("You should hear about  Rejections by", estdar_r))
    
    estdar_a <- date_calc(gadmint_car_a)
    print(paste("You should hear about  Acceptances by", estdar_a))

    return(data.frame(url = x, 
                      estd = estd, 
                      estdi = estdi, 
                      estdar_r = estdar_r, 
                      estdar_a = estdar_a,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    # ARG UNNEEDED FOR R 4.0+
           )
  })
}
```

#### Calls

```r
df_list1 <- grad("https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250")
# [1] "You should hear SOMETHING  by 03-21"
# [1] "You should hear about Interviews by  12-18"
# [1] "You should hear about  Rejections by 03-21"
# [1] "You should hear about  Acceptances by 03-20"

df_list2 <- grad("https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250", 
                 "https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=harvard&t=a&o=&pp=250")
# [1] "You should hear SOMETHING  by 03-21"
# [1] "You should hear about Interviews by  12-18"
# [1] "You should hear about  Rejections by 03-21"
# [1] "You should hear about  Acceptances by 03-20"
# [1] "You should hear SOMETHING  by 03-05"
# [1] "You should hear about Interviews by  12-18"
# [1] "You should hear about  Rejections by 03-04"
# [1] "You should hear about  Acceptances by 03-07"
```

#### Data

```r
str(df_list1)
# List of 1
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ url     : chr "https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250"
#   ..$ estd    : chr "03-21"
#   ..$ estdi   : chr "12-18"
#   ..$ estdar_r: chr "03-21"
#   ..$ estdar_a: chr "03-20"

str(df_list2)
# List of 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ url     : chr "https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250"
#   ..$ estd    : chr "03-21"
#   ..$ estdi   : chr "12-18"
#   ..$ estdar_r: chr "03-21"
#   ..$ estdar_a: chr "03-20"
#  $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ url     : chr "https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=harvard&t=a&o=&pp=250"
#   ..$ estd    : chr "03-05"
#   ..$ estdi   : chr "12-18"
#   ..$ estdar_r: chr "03-04"
#   ..$ estdar_a: chr "03-07"
```

Even combine list of multiple data frames into a single data frame:

```r
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list2)
final_df

#                                                                                url  estd estdi estdar_r estdar_a
# 1 https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=Stanford+University&t=a&o=&pp=250 03-21 12-18    03-21    03-20
# 2             https://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=harvard&t=a&o=&pp=250 03-05 12-18    03-04    03-07
```

Comment: Thank you! :D @Parfait